# VS 2012 Express não acessa TFS 2012 Express

Tags: team-foundation-server

Fiz a instalação do TFS 2012 Express num servidor e está tudo instalado certinho. O acesso web pelo endereço **ipdoservidor:8080/tfs**  normalmente.

Porém quando eu tento buscar pelo VS 2012 que tenho na minha máquina, ele não consegue conectar de jeito nenhum.

Retorna a mensagem abaixo:

http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/granth/WindowsLiveWriter/TroubleshootingyourconnectiontoTFS_11D9A/image_2.png

As permissões para o meu usuário estão todas certas. Já fiz a instalação do TFS na minha máquina e no servidor e continua a mesma coisa.

Já fiz algumas alterações no REGEDIT, apaguei cache do TFS e nada.

Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Me desculpe questionar, mas você já tentou desinstalar tudo e reinstalar novamente?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, já tentei sim. Já fiz de tudo, mas não acessa cara. Tá complicado. :(

Comment: Você está usando AD? Pela Web você faz o acesso na máquina client?

Comment: @Brandão,  Sim. Aqui uso AD. Pela Web ele faz acesso normalmente. Acessa tudo, porém pelo VS é que o trem dá problema.

Comment: Printa a tela de cadastro do servidor no Visual Studio, como vc está colocando a URL...

Answer (score 1):

muito obrigado pelo empenho.

Mas depois de tanto tentar eu consegui identificar o problema.

O Team Foundation cria uma aplicação **TFS** no *IIS*. E existem as Autenticações que são usadas nessa aplicação. Por padrão, a opção de **Autenticação Anônima** estava desabilitada. Então eu habilitei a **Autenticação Anônima** e funcionou.

Tive um outro problema depois disso, onde não conseguia criar os projetos, mas ai foi só dar permissão pro meu usuário do AD na pasta ***C:/Windows/Temp*** no servidor e resolveu.

Fiquei bastante tempo futucando pra conseguir resolver e de tanto fuçar, achei a solução. Não sei se é a única solução ou se é a solução correta, mas é a solução que funcionou pra mim.

Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar.

Espero que eu consiga ajudar alguém com essa solução.

Valeu.